# Using contract in other modules in a multi-module maven project

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I have a multi-module Maven project. structure look like this:

```
 Parent
    |-- ModuleA
            |-- contracts
    |-- ModuleB
            |-- src/test
                |-- B
```

The contracts are located in Module A, How can I refer this contract in maven plugin. I used this config, but it' doesn't work:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <version>3.0.2</version>

    <configuration>
        <contractsDirectory>${project.basedir}/moduleA/contracts</contractsDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I got this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:3.0.2:generateStubs (default-generateStubs) on project xxxxxx: Stubs could not be found: [xxxxxxxxxx\target\stubs] .
```

Comment: If the plugin is defined in `ModuleB` then you have to use the `${maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory}` property to reference the `Parent` directory.

Comment: it doesn't generate any test class and get this error: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:3.0.2:generateStubs (default-generateStubs) on project xxxxxx: Stubs could not be found: [xxxxxxxxxx\target\stubs] .

Comment: the same config work if I put the contract in the same module

Comment: What if you use the `stubs://` protocol and point the `contractsUrl` to it like in the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current/reference/html/project-features.html#features-stub-runner-stubs-protocol

Comment: If your projects going to expand, you might want to give a try at [Pact Broker](https://docs.pact.io/getting_started/sharing_pacts)